Delete Matching Rows from 3 Sheets After Detecting Duplicate Job Numbers in the 4th
I have a multi-sheet spreadsheet that contains job numbers in column A  of sheets 1, 2, 3, & 4
When a duplicate number comes into Sheet4 Col A, a formula copies the number to Col B adding a ^ {vers number}.  So MO123456 in Col A becomes MO123456^1 in Col B (which increments for each additional duplicate of that  number).
For each number that is flagged as a duplicate, (in Sheet4  Col B) I want the script to delete the rows of the matching numbers in Sheets 1, 2, & 3.
I found a script here that I was able to modify to look only at the last row of Col B.  But instead of  comparing this cell against the other three sheets with indexOf, I need it to detect numbers with the ^ but return the job number only for the CheckForDup function.  If an original number comes in, then it will copy to Col B with no ^ and the script should ignore it.
Finally I need to convert the script to onEdit  so when a new number comes into the last row of Col B, the script automatically triggers.
`
function removeDupsInOtherSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();  
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var s3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var s4s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  var s4 = s4s.getRange(s4s.getLastRow(),2,2,s4s.getLastColumn()).getValues()

  // iterate s4 and check in s1 & s2 & s3 if duplicate values exist
  var nS1 = [];
  var nS2 = [];
  var nS3 = [];
  var s4Col2 = [];// data in column2 of sheet4
  for(var n in s4){
    s4Col2.push(s4[n][0]);
  }
  for(var n in s1){ // iterate sheet1 and test col 1 vs col 2 lastRow in sheet4
    var noDup1 = checkForDup(s1[n],s4Col2)
    if(noDup1){nS1.push(noDup1)};// if not present in sheet4 then keep
  } 
  for(var n in s2){  // iterate sheet2 and test col 1 vs col 2 lastRow in sheet4
    var noDup2 = checkForDup(s2[n],s4Col2)
    if(noDup2){nS2.push(noDup2)};// if not present in sheet4 then keep
  }
  for(var n in s3){  // iterate sheet2 and test col 1 vs col 2 lastRow in sheet4
    var noDup3 = checkForDup(s3[n],s4Col2)
    if(noDup3){nS3.push(noDup3)};// if not present in sheet4 then keep
  }
 // Logger.log(nS1);// view result
 // Logger.log(nS2);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().clear();// clear and update sheets
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().clear();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().clear();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2,1,nS1.length,nS1[0].length).setValues(nS1);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(2,1,nS2.length,nS2[0].length).setValues(nS2);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(2,1,nS3.length,nS3[0].length).setValues(nS3);
}

function checkForDup(item,s){
//  Logger.log(s+' = '+item[0]+'  ?')
    if(s.indexOf(item[0])>-1){
      return null;
    }
  return item;
}

//string.slice(0,string.indexOf('^'));
//REGEXEXTRACT("^[^--]+")


Automatically Delete Matching Rows in 3 Sheets Upon Detecting Duplicate Job Numbers in Sheet 4
When a job number is entered in Sheet4, Column A, the script automatically generates a versioned job number in Column B. If the Job number appears again, its version in Column B will increment accordingly.
The script uses the onEdit trigger, so whenever a change is made in Sheet4, Column A, it automatically updates Column B with the correct version and deletes the matching rows in Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3.
You can try this code:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;


  if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet4" && range.getColumn() === 1) {
    const jobNumber = range.getValue();

    if (jobNumber) {

      const versionedJobNumber = generateJobNumber(jobNumber);
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).setValue(versionedJobNumber);

      removeMatchingRows(jobNumber);
    }
  }
}

function generateJobNumber(jobNumber) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  const data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  let version = 0;

  data.forEach((row) => {
    const existingJobNumber = row[0];
    if (existingJobNumber && existingJobNumber.split("^")[0] === jobNumber) {
      version++;
    }
  });

  return `${jobNumber}^${version}`;
}

function removeMatchingRows(jobNumber) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetsToCheck = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];

  sheetsToCheck.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) return;

    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const rowsToDelete = [];


    data.forEach((row, index) => {
      const baseJobNumber = row[0].split("^")[0];
      if (baseJobNumber === jobNumber) {
        rowsToDelete.push(index + 1);
      }
    });

    rowsToDelete.reverse().forEach(rowIndex => {
      sheet.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    });
  });
}

Sample Sheet:(Before)



Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet 4




MO112131
MO456789
MO654322
MO123456


MO123456
MO123456
MO123456




Sample Sheet:(After)



Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet 4





MO112131
MO456789
MO654322
MO123456
MO123456^1



Reference:
onEdit(e)
includes()
forEach()
if/else

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. If OP doesn't dispute it, there is no need to show a solution works.

@TheMaster  Thanks, I already changed the image into a Markdown table.

Alma_Matters; This script is AMAZING! I just need a couple of tweaks. When it generates MO123456^1 in Col B, it is deleting that job number from the 3 sheets. However the version number^1 represents and original job and should not be deleted. Only if the version number is ^2 or higher should it delete. I'm not sure how to adjust for this. Also Row 1 has headers and must be protected. Thx.

@Scrib68 Glad to know it works! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

It seems to me that your initial question has already been addressed. Please only ask one question per post. Any followup questions must be posted as new questions instead. @Scrib68
